# How do I add a new key-value pair in a smart way to a dict if the key is already contained in the dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

As the title says, I want to write a function that automatically detects,
when adding a key value pair, if this key is already included in the dict.

If this is the case, an ascending number should be added to the key and the slightly changed key value pair should be added to the dict.

As seen in the following example, my current horrible approach is to query each case individually, how can I do that in a smart way for any number of keys with the same name.

```
            if "begin time" in day_dict.keys():
                if "begin time2" in day_dict.keys():
                    if "begin time3" in day_dict.keys():
                        day_dict["begin time4"] = value
                    else:
                        day_dict["begin time3"] = value 
                else:
                    day_dict["begin time2"] = value
            else:
                day_dict["begin time"] = value
```

Comment: you can use `setdefault` as `day_dict.setdefault("begin time", {})` or better use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the `collections` module

Comment: Btw, not your question, but you can check membership of dictionaries directly; you don't need `.keys()`. `if "begin time" in day_dict` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help:

```py
def add_key_value(key, value, mydict, i=0):
    new_key = key
    if i:
        new_key = key+str(i+1)
    if new_key in mydict:
        add_key_value(''.join(i for i in new_key if not i.isdigit()), value, mydict, i+1)
    else:
        mydict[new_key] = value

day_dict = {}
add_key_value('begin time', 1, day_dict)
print(day_dict)
add_key_value('begin time', 1, day_dict)
print(day_dict)
add_key_value('begin time', 1, day_dict)
print(day_dict)
add_key_value('begin time', 1, day_dict)
print(day_dict)
```

Output

```
{'begin time': 1}
{'begin time': 1, 'begin time2': 1}
{'begin time': 1, 'begin time2': 1, 'begin time3': 1}
{'begin time': 1, 'begin time2': 1, 'begin time3': 1, 'begin time4': 1}
```

**Note**:

```
''.join(i for i in new_key if not i.isdigit())
```

this line removes digits from `new_key`.

eg: **without** this line, the following code

```
add_key_value('begin time3', 1, day_dict)
```

would generate the new key as `'begin time32'` ie `'begin time3'` + `'2'`

Comment: great, that's exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: @JulioReckin Hi, wait there was a bug I just fixed it, please take a look I'll add the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

```
setdefault(key[, default])
```

"If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None."

Example:

```
day_dict.setdefault('begin time', 'default value')
```

Comment: I think that's not exactly what I'm a searching for, I mean with this approach the key which is already in the dict will not add to the dict under a new similar name isn't it? What I forget to say is that the value is not always the same, therefore the key value pair should always be added to the dict.